# jQuery .closest not locating correct p element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to determine why some of my code isn't working, even though it appears to be very straight forward.

As you can see below, I'm determining that the img tag has contains the class size-full, and then the intention is to find the closest `p` element (which is the element that houses the `img` element) b and add that the class `CM-blog-image`. Why isn't this working?

```
if($('.entry-content p img').hasClass('size-full')) {

        $(this).closest('p').addClass('CM-blog-image');
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="entry-content" itemprop="text">
<p> // <-- Need to add class to this p element
<img src="/example.jpg" class='size-full'>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show your html?

Comment: You can use find instead of closest.

Comment: @HarshSanghani I added the HTML markup.

Comment: @HarshSanghani: `.find()` will travese the DOM only in top to Down pattern but `.closest()` does the opposite.

Comment: $(this).parent('p').addClass('CM-blog-image');

Comment: try these it works..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use like this:

```
$('.entry-content img.size-full').parent().addClass('CM-blog-image');
               //or you may use   ^^ closest('p')
```

Comment: this makes it more specific to the DOM structure

Comment: @Delto Glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it using simple traversal methods. No need to use `.each()`

```
$('.entry-content p img.size-full') //Find image with the class
     .closest('p') //Traverse up to paragraph element
     .addClass('CM-blog-image');  //Add the required class
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to add class to each element found.

```
$('.entry-content p img').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('size-full'))
        $(this).closest('p').addClass('CM-blog-image');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have p tag and image tag immediate next of entry-content class. Use like below. it should work.

```
if($('.entry-content > p > img').hasClass('size-full')) {

        $(this).closest('p').addClass('CM-blog-image');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//select img with class size-full
 var elm = $('.entry-content p img.size-full');

  // add CM-blog-image to closest parent p
 elm.closest('p').addClass('CM-blog-image');
```